# An icon of my logo in my email signature flies to the far right of the web browser, but I want its position to be exact

Tags: html, css, email, signature

I have an email signature with one icon that seems to fly to the right hand side of the screen when opened in some web browsers. I want to select its exact position.

It works for me but not on another persons web browser

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="64" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; 
               font-size:18px; font-style:bold;">
        <strong>Oliver Loweth</strong>
        <br>
        <em style="font-size:17px; font-weight:400;">Senior Partner</em>
      </td>
      <td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="35" width="200" vertical-align="center">
        <a href="https://www.technicalalliance.com.au/"><img src="http://d4625.mysite.westnethosting.com.au/Images/ta_logo_gold.png" alt="link to Technical Alliance website" border="0" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

No error messages - just that this icon (ta_logo_gold.png) flies to the right of screen in some browsers but I want it to stay in position horizontally - a certain distance from the left.

Answer (score 1):

**Alignment**

Firstly, `vertical-align` isn't a HTML attribute, it's a CSS property. To align vertically on a table you can use [valign](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) like so.

```html
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="35" width="200" valign="center">
```

You can also add [align](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp) to your container and set it as left, so the icon will always be pushed left.

```html
<td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="35" width="200" valign="center" align="left">
```

**Why not use `float` or `position`?**

Usually you could use them to get what you are after, but as you are working on an email, it's always good to check the CSS support for properties you are calling as a lot of clients dont support some common properties like `position` as seen on [CampaignMonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/).

Comment: Thanks Karl, I have made those changes - i'll let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to use the `float` property in a `<style>` and set it to left.

```
<style>
    img {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

this should stop the logo flying off to the right. If that doesn't work, then try using `position:absolute` and setting `top` and `left` to your preferred position.

Comment: Adele welcome to stack overflow! Just a quick word of advice: site etiquette forbids that people say "thank you" in the comments. It may seem counterintuitive, but the reason behind it is solid: it's to stop people from clogging up comment sections with "thanks", leaving room for other things like clarification comments. The best way to show your appreciation is to accept answers and upvote them!

Comment: to accept an answer, press the green tick on the left. This will give me 15 reputation, and you 2 reputation. to "upvote" an answer, you need the "vote up" privilege (see the privileges page) and then just press the upwards-pointing triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `vertical-align` as a `td` attribute. `vertical-align` is a CSS property and not a HTML attribute. Furthermore, because you're sending an email we need keep it simple and pure HTML and Some CSS properties may not be supported for all the clients. Now you need to add two attributes to achieve your goal. The `valign` attribute specifies the vertical alignment of the content in a cell and this is its syntax:

```
<td valign="top|middle|bottom|baseline">
```

Finally, to align your icon to the left we will use the `align` attribute. This specifies the horizontal alignment of the content in a cell and this is its syntax:

```
<td align="left|right|center|justify|char">
```

Here you can see how it works:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="64" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; 
               font-size:18px; font-style:bold;">
        <strong>Oliver Loweth</strong>
        <br>
        <em style="font-size:17px; font-weight:400;">Senior Partner Left</em>
      </td>
      <td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="35" width="200" valign="center" align="left">
        <a href="https://www.technicalalliance.com.au/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bF9SfLM.png" alt="link to Technical Alliance website" border="0" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="64" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; 
               font-size:18px; font-style:bold;">
        <strong>Oliver Loweth</strong>
        <br>
        <em style="font-size:17px; font-weight:400;">Senior Partner Right</em>
      </td>
      <td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="35" width="200" valign="center" align="right">
        <a href="https://www.technicalalliance.com.au/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bF9SfLM.png" alt="link to Technical Alliance website" border="0" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```